# When I use WebStorm open the vue project, there is Import decralations are not supported error

Tags: webstorm

> Import decralations are not supported by current JavaScript version

When I use WebStorm open the vue project.

My code is bellow:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

The snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`import xxx from xxx` is a new feature in ECMAScript6, you can find in [there](http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport).

In the WebStorm you should change the JavaScript language version to `ECMAScript6`.

WebStorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Thanks @lena:

There is a easy way to realize it:

> hit Alt+Enter on the error message, choose Change Javascript language version to ECMAScript 6 from the popup

Comment: Note that this can be done right in the editor: hit `Alt+Enter` on the error message, choose **Change Javascript language version to ECMAScript 6** from the popup